# Is there any limit on the number of product attributes which can be made is_filterable_in_search = 1 in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, solr

We are using `Magento Enterprise 1.10` and `SOLR` as our catalog search engine.

We are facing one major issue in our live website is that whenever we start increasing number of search filterable attributes in our system, after certain limit catalog search breaks. It gives no search result ?

I tried to look at the Magento exception logs it says:

> 2014-12-16T21:07:53+00:00 ERR (3): 
>   exception 'Exception' with message '"400" Status: Bad Request' in /var/www/site/lib/Apache/Solr/Service.php:334

I tried to log the URL request made by `Magento` to `SOLR` during catalog search & it basically makes 3 request to `SOLR` and in the third request it has huge number of parameters in facet.field request URL.

What could be the possible issue? Is there any limitation on no. of facet.field request made by `Magento` to `SOLR`

Is there some configuration changes is required on `Magento` or `SOLR` side to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is no limit to keep number of Filterable Attributes in Base Magento.

Please check your PHP Execution Time on Server side. This might be the issue.

Are you using a Cron or Command line argument to run the Reindex or Running the Reindex from Admin ?

Try running the reindex through Command line and check once if it works.